# simplest python graphical interface?

Tags: python, graphics, monitoring

Using python I'm traying to monitor a small network, I did this using zabbix before and it work perfectly, zabbix is much bigger than what i want to do.
just ping every device in a text file.
I want to graphically visualize the results, opengl, matplotlib.. are very strong but are bigger than what I want to do.
Is there a python module that can do like this result:
[example of graphical representation of results (map)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4BFN.png)

I just want to keep things very simple.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. 
Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named 
["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). 
And more importantly, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). 
You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: sorry sir, this kind of question is not accepted on satckoverflow ? i'm searching for advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use **[graph-tool](https://graph-tool.skewed.de)** if you're looking for a tool to analyze a network.

Graph-tool is an efficient Python module for manipulation and statistical analysis of graphs (a.k.a. networks).  Conveniently draw your graphs, using a variety of algorithms and output formats (including to the screen).